# C updating an array index that is a struct member also updates all previous indexes

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a struct as follows:

```
struct Stack {
int top;
struct Token data[size]};
};
```

And the following push Method:

```
void push(struct Stack *st, struct Token tok) {
(*st).top++;
(*st).data[(*st).top] = tok;
}
```

Every time I call the push method on a struct Stack s, it updates the whole array s.data (until index top) with the new value **instead of only** the specified index data[top]. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
struct Stack stack1;
    stack1.top = -1;

    readNext();
    //currentToken.value == "class"
    push(&stack1,currentToken);

    readNext();
    //currentToken.value == "test"
    push(&stack1,currentToken);

    readNext();
    //currentToken.value == "{"
    push(&stack1,currentToken);

    readNext();
    //currentToken.value == "int"
    push(&stack1,currentToken);

    printStack(stack1);
```

output is:

```
int
int
int
int
```

Comment: Show more code. BTW `(*st).` should be written `st->`.

Comment: @michael waltz: The push method is being called as follows: push(&stack1,currentToken);

Comment: Show us both the code calling push and also the code which tells you that the whole array got updated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be incrementing `st->top` *after* you do the push? As in `st->data[st->top++] = tok;`

Comment: @ weather: I initialize top to be -1(for another purpose), Then I want to first increment top so that top == 0 and then push to index 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every time I call the push method on a struct Stack s, it updates the whole array s.data (until index top) with the new value instead of only the specified index data[top].

No, it doesn't.  Only one element of `d->data` is modified.  The value of the token passed (by copying its value) to the `push()` function is copied into one element the that array.

> Any ideas why this is happening?

You think you see all the array elements being updated because you have some kind of aliasing going on.  The `push()` function is in the clear -- it is almost certainly whatever function you are using to generate new tokens that is the problem.

For example, you may have something like this:

```
/* Hypothetical example */

struct Token {
    int type;
    char *value;
};

char buffer[100];

void readTokens() {
    Struct Stack stack = { -1 };
    struct Token tok;

    while (scanf("%s", buffer) == 1) {
        tok.value = buffer;  /* the error is here in this case */
        tok.type = 42;
        push(&stack, tok);
    }
}
```

Note that `value` members of all tokens involved in that case, including all the copies, point to *the same* `char[]`, whose contents are updated each time a new token is read.  Each one must instead receive a pointer to a copy of the array.  In general, such copies would need to be dynamically allocated, such as via `strdup()`.

**UPDATE:**

The additional code you posted is not conclusive, but it is consistent with my diagnosis.  You would observe the behavior you describe if `currentToken.value` is a `char *` (as opposed to a `char[]`) and `readNext()` modifies the array to which it points rather than assigning a new pointer, just as I described above.

Comment: Thanks, I had a blank out moment. I need to copy the value of currentToken in the push method instead of setting array[top] to point to currentToken which is constantly changing.

Comment: @Zak00, no, you don't get it.  You are already copying `currentToken` when you pass it to `push()`, and again when you assign the that copy to an array element.  The problem is that what you are copying includes a pointer to a static buffer, or something similar.